# How to get user's informations in spring boot and thymleaf?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I did a web application using Spring boot, Spring Security and MySQL .

I want to add a page where I show all user's information. Now  I can just get all the users I have in my DB.

I found that there is a function `find(index)` ;but I don't know what to put as an index ,is there anything in Spring boot can help?

This is the model user :

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    //.........
}
```

My userRepository :

```
public interface UserrRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{}
```

The user Controller :

```
 public String home(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepo.findAll());
        return "stat";
    }
```

And my html page :

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>

                <th>firstName</th>
                <th>lastName</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
                <td th:text="${user.id}">Id</td>
                <td th:text="${user.firstName}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${user.lastName}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${user.password}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${user.email}">Name</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the issue you are facing? Does the current implementation using `UserrRepository.findAll()` give an error?

Comment: My problem is that findAll give me all users I have in my DB but I need when someOne connect getting just its info (name,password,phone,email ....) ,Can you help me??

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358478/how-can-i-display-the-current-logged-in-user-with-spring-boot-thymeleaf?rq=1

Comment: No , I want to get data from mysql  like  excuting query select * from table where email=email of current user  ;There is any function that can do this ?*

Comment: You can create a method in your `UserrRepository` interface,  `List<User> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress)` and the JPA repository will generate the query for you and automatically return the list of matching users. You can read more about writing queries in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation